# Unable to use "u" filter

Tags: twig, symfony4

I am unable to get my symfony 4 application to run.

The error I get below indicates the filter is not found despite making sure `twig/string-extra` which includes `"symfony/string": "^5.0"`is in my composer file.

I have the activated twig extensions in twig_extensions.yml as follows:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    public: false
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

    # Uncomment any lines below to activate that Twig extension
    #Twig\Extensions\ArrayExtension: ~
    #Twig\Extensions\DateExtension: ~
    Twig\Extensions\IntlExtension: ~
    #Twig\Extensions\TextExtension: ~
```

The specific line causing the issue looks like this:
    `{{- label|u.truncate(100) -}}`

The file in vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig line 175

> Unknown "u" filter. Did you mean "round", "upper", "column", "reduce",
>   "default", "truncate", "humanize", "yaml_dump", "url_encode",
>   "number_format", "sonata_slugify", "sonata_truncate",
>   "localizednumber", "sonata_urlsafeid", "localizedcurrency",
>   "knp_menu_as_string", "sonata_status_class", "form_encode_currency",
>   "doctrine_pretty_query", "doctrine_replace_query_parameters"?

Comment: Can you show the line of code that is generating the error?

Comment: Did you register the extra extension within twig? See [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service)

Comment: @NicoHaase This is a filter that should already be in Twig so my thinking is that the registration should work with auto wiring?

Comment: This is not a default twig filter as seen [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/). Also the extension is called `StringExtension `  and is not present in your yaml

Comment: Thank you, you're right. Apologies for my ignorance. Issue is fixed

Comment: No problem at all :)